# How to enable php extension intl programmatically

Tags: php, yii2

I have to convert the amount in words in Yii2. I used

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asSpellout('125');
```

to convert. I have enabled intl extension in the php.ini file. The same thing I want to use in the server too. Is there any way to enable the intl extension via code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled the extension in php.ini it is available to you on your server.
If by server you mean a different server (you local PC is also a server in this case), you cannot enable extension programmatically and will have to contact your hosting provider for the same.